# Common place for creating files on various platforms (non-user-specific)

Tags: java, android, windows, linux, directory

I write cross-platform java app and I need some place where I can store some amount of files. These files will be used by another java application that may run under another user. This mean that I cannot use:

```
System.getProperty("user.home");
```

since I may have no permissions to read/write these files. What I need is some way to get non-user-specific folder where every app can create/read/delete files (something like "C:\ProgramData" for windows).
Is there a cross-platform way to get such folder(at least for Windows and Linux), or if there is no any - what is the best way to get such folders for Windows(should work on XP-7), Linux and Android.
Any pieces of puzzle are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of such such a cross-platform folder which is additionally readable by all users. But you can:

- Define a specific folder for each OS, `commons-lang` may help you determining the platform (see [SystemUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/SystemUtils.html))
- Check if the folder read/writeable for the current user during application start-up.

Using a central configuration (where the data exchange folder is defined for this installation) may also be an option, but this depends on the packaging of your project.